# iOS SDK -> FBLoginDialog Login Delegate Bug

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

FBLoginDialog -> Start Login -> Press on the X button -> See call back (from FBLoginDialog) to  "fbDialogNotLogin", then receive call back to fbDialogLogin "fbDialogLogin:expirationDate:"

FYI (@FB Dev's) You should add a boolean flag or something.